# SAS vertical merge

Tags: sas

i have a problem joining two datasets verticaly. I have two datasets that have some matching and some different variables. I need to verticaly join these two datasets and get all variables from first dataset and only matching variables from other dataset as a result.

```
Dataset 1:  
ID V1 V2 V3 V4  
1  aa bb 10 99     
2  bb cc 20 99   

Dataset 2:  
ID V1 V3 V5  
3  xx 11 x1  
4  yy 12 2x  

Result needed:  
ID V1 V2 V3 V4  
1  aa bb 10 99  
2  bb cc 20 99  
3  xx  . 11  .  
4  yy  . 12  .
```

Any help? thanks!

Comment: Can't you just do `data out; set dataset1 dataset2; run;` or `proc append base=dataset1 data=dataset2 force; run;` ? - more info here which I found on the first page of google results: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a001081414.htm

Comment: append with force option worked as needed. thanks.

Comment: @thelatemail Please make that an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a couple of options:

```
data out;
  set  dataset1
       dataset2;
run;
```

or

```
proc append
  base=dataset1 data=dataset2 
  force; 
run;
```

There is more info here which I found on the first page of Google results:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/…